# Uncommitted transactions in Plone + SqlAlchemy + MySql

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, plone, zope

We have a hybrid web application integrating a MySql db with Plone (last upgrade was to Plone 4.0), using collective.tin, collective.lead and SqlAlchemy.

Ok, I know that collective.tin never was released and collective.lead has been superseded; however all things work (almost) perfectly since a few years.

Recently we experienced a very strange behaviour and are looking for help in order to understand it.

Among others, we have 2 Plone content types, say A and B, defined by subclassing collective.tin, and the corresponding innodb MySql tables; rows of B have a foreign key towards A.

In the time span of 15-20 minutes, 2 different users created 3 A objects and some 10-20 B objects that weren't committed to MySql but were indexed by Plone; queries I executed with a MySql client from the linux shell weren't able to find those A rows (didn't look for B rows); however, queries executed through the web application (the aforementioned components stack) by those 2 users, and also by other users, occasionally were still finding and correctly visualizing some of those 3 A objects.

Only after I restarted the Zope instance, it was possible to resume normal activity from the Plone web interface; 3 A rows and many B rows were still missing from the MySql db, but the autoincrement counter showed the expected increment; I had to remove 3 invalid brains for A objects from the Plone index (didn't worry for B objects).

Any suggestion on possible causes and on how to investigate the problem?

Comment: What version of `sqlalchemy` is used?

Comment: sqlalchemy 0.4.8 ; since I used collective.tin 0.3 (svn/unreleased), I remember that I wasn't able to use a more recent version of sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 4):

We had the exact same problem with sqlalchemy 0.4; the session would get out of sync with the actual database contents. The problem was somewhat masked in our case because users were sent to specific backends in the cluster through session affinity. If the affinity was lost suddenly messages had disappeared. The exact details are a little hazy, because I cannot locate the correct (ancient) revision history of the fix I put in place.

From what I can glean from context is that the session identity map prevents the session from requiring the database for objects it retrieved before. It thus won't see changes made to these objects in different sessions.

The fix is to call `.expire_all()` on the session after each and every commit or rollback; SQLAlchemy 0.5 and up does this automatically (`autoexpire=True` on the session, now called `expire_on_commit` I believe), but for 0.4 you'll need to register a `SessionExtension` to do this for you.

Lucky for you, we also use `collective.lead` for this project, so my fix is your fix:

```
# The identity map should be flushed on commit.
# SQLAlchemy 0.5 does this properly, but in 0.4 we need to do this via
# a SesssionExtension.

from sqlalchemy import __version__
if __version__[:3] == '0.4':
    from sqlalchemy.orm.session import SessionExtension

    class ExpireAllSessionExtension(SessionExtension):
        def after_commit(self, session):
            """Expire the identity-map on commit"""
            session.expire_all()

        def after_rollback(self, session):
            """Expire the identity-map on rollback"""
            session.expire_all()

    def installExtension():
        # Patch collective.lead.database to let us install the extension
        # on the session created there.
        from collective.lead.database import Database
        old_session = Database.session.fget
        def session(self):
            session = old_session(self)
            if session.extension is None:
                session.extension = ExpireAllSessionExtension()
            return session
        Database.session = property(session)
else:
    def installExtension():
        pass
```

When defining the mapper, you install this extension with:

```
from .sessionexpiration import installExtension

# Ensure that sessions get properly expired on commit and rollback.
installExtension()
```

Comment: Thank you very very much, Martijn!
I didn't try your fix yet but, based on what you write, I also think that we have been very lucky in finding a guy willing to share his experience on this so specific topic.